# How can I disable or customize the image preview, which displays when a user hovers over an app's icon on the taskbar?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, taskbar, aero

In Windows with Aero... When the user hovers their mouse over the application's icon, a small preview of the app appears just above the taskbar. I'm looking for any information regarding how I can disable this preview or change/customize what appears in this little preview image box.

Note that I'm not looking to disable Aero features as a user - I'm looking to control this in-app.

Thank you in advance for answers!

Comment: Try this question for an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640601/writing-to-the-windows-7-preview-window-area

Comment: The first example (DocumentReader) on this page shows how to modify the preview image: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/02/12/windows-7-taskbar-apis.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is wrapper lib of the API, which controls these features in Windows - Jump Lists, Icon Overlay, Progress Bar, Tabbed Thumbnails, and Thumbnail Toolbars
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack